# Using Lua to index XML objects

Tags: xml, lua

I currently have a bunch of boxes that look similar to

```
<Texture name="uiBox01">
    *Other content*
</Texture>
```

This continues for 18 boxes (uiBox18). In Lua I am capable of referencing the boss and changing its color via

```
uiBox01:SetVertexColor(r,g,b)
```

The problem is I may or may not need more boxes for an operation. The given operation could utilize 2 boxes on its first pass and maybe 8 on the next. As such it needs to be dynamic instead of static.

Ultimately I would like to use an array with Lua such that

```
uiBox[1] = uiBox01 --something similar to this
```

so that I can specify the next index more efficiently. Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT: The XML used is WoW UI XML it's very similar to basic XML.

Comment: It's 'Lua', not 'LUA'

Comment: Also we need more information, like what XML library you are using.

Comment: Added which XML I'm using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I got your question right. I assume what you want to do is be able to refer to a box using an index in an array, rather than a variable name.

```
i=5  -- set from somewhere,maybe a loop
-- after some time
myBox = boxes[i]
```

I am not familiar with WoW, but I presume that uiBox01 is a global variable created by WoW somehow.

In Lua global variables are stored in _G array, index being the name of the variable. So

```
uiBox01 == _G['uiBox01']  -- returns true
```

So following must work for you

```
i=5  -- set from somewhere,maybe a loop
-- after some time
myBox = _G['uiBox'..i]
```

Extending it to take care of prefixing zero if i is a single digit

```
i=5  -- set from somewhere,maybe a loop
-- after some time
myBox = _G['uiBox'.. (i < 10 and '0' or '' ) .. i] -- concatenate zero in middle if i<10
```

Let me know if you were looking for something else.